# React input tag disabled prop issue

Tags: reactjs, disabled-input

> I am trying to build a login form in React.js. I want to enable/disable Login button based on results return by validate method. React throws error 'Invalid value for prop `disabled` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.'. Does anyone have came across same error? Help me to understand what is going wrong here?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "../common/input";
import Joi from "joi-browser";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = {
    account: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {
    username: Joi.string().required().label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string().required().label("Password"),
  };

  abortEarly = {
    abortEarly: false,
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const errors = this.validate();
    if (errors) return;
    console.log("submitted");
  };

  validate = () => {
    const result = Joi.validate(
      this.state.account,
      this.schema,
      this.abortEarly
    );
    const errors = {};
    if (!result.error) return null;
    result.error.details.map((detail) => {
      errors[detail.path[0]] = detail.message;
      return detail.path[0];
    });
    // console.log(errors);
    this.setState({ errors });
    return errors;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const propertyTobeValidated = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(propertyTobeValidated, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const error = this.validateProperty(currentTarget);
    if (error) errors[currentTarget.name] = error;
    else delete errors[currentTarget.name];
    const account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[currentTarget.name] = currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({ account, errors });
  };

  render() {
    const { account, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            value={account.username}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors.username}
          ></Input>
          <Input
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            value={account.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors.password}
          ></Input>

          <button disabled={this.validate} className="btn btn-primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: disabled is a boolean attribute not a function. Your this.validate is a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled is a boolean property, meaning it can only have a value of true or false. Instead of a boolean, your validate function is returning an object, thus React throws an "Invalid value" error. In order to fix this you could check if the result of `this.validate` is null:

```
<button 
    disabled={(this.validate() !== null)} 
    className="btn btn-primary"
>
    Login
</button>
```

Also, you forgot to call your `this.validate` at all :)

Regarding the "Maximum update depth...", you should remove the `this.setState` from the `this.validate`, because you are already putting the error in state in the `handleChange` method.

Comment: I tried your solution. I am now facing Error: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." I am using React Version 16.9. Regarding your suggestion, in react we pass the reference of method on any action; hence I put disabled={this.validate}.

Comment: In this case you shouldn't pass a reference to the method, but the value it returns instead, because the `button` expects a value in the `disabled` prop

Comment: I modified my answer, now it should help with the Maximum update depth

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. I had a wrong conception that, in react for each props of tag we need to pass reference of method.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "../common/input";
import Joi from "joi-browser";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = {
    account: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {
    username: Joi.string().required().label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string().required().label("Password"),
  };

  abortEarly = {
    abortEarly: false,
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const errors = this.validate();
    if (errors) return;
    console.log("submitted");
  };

  validate = () => {
    const result = Joi.validate(
      this.state.account,
      this.schema,
      this.abortEarly
    );
    const errors = {};
    if (!result.error) return false;
    result.error.details.map((detail) => {
      errors[detail.path[0]] = detail.message;
      return detail.path[0];
    });
    // console.log(errors);
    this.setState({ errors });
    return true;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const propertyTobeValidated = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(propertyTobeValidated, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const error = this.validateProperty(currentTarget);
    if (error) errors[currentTarget.name] = error;
    else delete errors[currentTarget.name];
    const account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[currentTarget.name] = currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({ account, errors });
  };

  render() {
    const { account, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            value={account.username}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors.username}
          ></Input>
          <Input
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            value={account.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors.password}
          ></Input>

          <button disabled={this.validate} className="btn btn-primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

`validate` method should return boolean (true or false)

Comment: It's a fine solution, but I would argue that it's more maintainable if rendering was determined entirely by state.  I'd either add another piece of state that dictated the presence of errors in addition to the piece of state that is an object of errors, or perhaps convert the `errors` state to an array, which contains a `length` property, so `<button disabled={this.errors.length}`

Comment: @Shiladitya I tried your suggested solution. Still I am facing the same error. Login button is enabled by default. I am using React 16.9.